# Error recovering Local SID

Tags: ldap, samba, domain-controller, openldap, raspbian

## What is fine :

LDAP is alright, and can be accessed with phpLdapadmin without problem.
LDAP hybris95home.local contains "dn=admin,dc=hybris95home,dc=local" value.

## What is wrong:

Using `net getlocalsid` provides this output:

> smbldap_search_domain_info: Adding domain info for RASPBERRYPI failed
>   with NT_STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL   pdb_init_ldapsam: WARNING: Could not get
>   domain info, nor add one to the domain. We cannot work reliably
>   without it.   pdb backend
>   ldapsam:"ldap://raspberrypi.hybris95home.local/" did not correctly
>   init (error was NT_STATUS_CANT_ACCESS_DOMAIN_INFO)   WARNING: Could
>   not open passdb

Also, `smbd` does not start correctly. (See below for further details)

## Versions used :

### OS :

Linux raspberrypi.hybris95home.local 4.4.34-v7+ #930 SMP Wed Nov 23 15:20:41 GMT 2016 armv7l GNU/Linux (Raspbian)

### Ldap :

@(#) $OpenLDAP: slapd  (Apr 15 2015 10:45:41) $
        buildd@bm-wb-04:/build/openldap-omOdCq/openldap-2.4.40+dfsg/debian/build/servers/slapd

### Samba :

Samba v4.2.10-Debian

## Additional Information

### /etc/hostname

> raspberrypi.hybris95home.local

### /etc/hosts

> 127.0.0.1       localhost
>   ::1             localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
>   ff02::1         ip6-allnodes
>   ff02::2         ip6-allrouters
>
> 127.0.1.1       raspberrypi.hybris95home.local raspberrypi

### /etc/samba/smb.conf

> [global]
>           workgroup = HYBRIS95HOME
>           netbios name = RASPBERRYPI
>           dns proxy = no
>           log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
>           max log size = 1000
>           syslog = 0
>           panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
>           security = user
>           ldap passwd sync = Yes
>           passdb backend = ldapsam:"ldap://raspberrypi.hybris95home.local/"
>           ldap admin dn = cn=admin,dc=hybris95home,dc=local
>           ldap suffix = dc=hybris95home,dc=local
>           ldap group suffix = ou=Groups
>           ldap user suffix = ou=Users
>           ldap machine suffix = ou=Computers
>           logon path =
>           logon home =
>           socket options = TCP_NODELAY SO_RCVBUF=8192 SO_SNDBUF=8192
>           case sensitive = No
>           default case = lower
>           preserve case = yes
>           short preserve case = Yes
>           socket options = TCP_NODELAY
>           ldap ssl = off

### /etc/smbldap-tools/smbldap.conf

> sambaDomain="hybris95home"
>   masterLDAP="RASPBERRYPI"
>   masterPort="389"
>   slaveLDAP="RASPBERRYPI"
>   slavePort="389"
>   suffix="dc=hybris95home,dc=local"
>   usersdn="ou=Users,${suffix}"
>   computersdn="ou=Computers,${suffix}"
>   groupsdn="ou=Groups,${suffix}"
>   sambaUnixIdPooldn="sambaDomainName=${sambaDomain},${suffix}"
>   scope="sub"
>   password_hash="SSHA"
>   password_crypt_salt_format="%s"
>   userLoginShell="/bin/bash"
>   userHome="/home/%U"
>   userHomeDirectoryMode="700"
>   userGecos="System User"
>   defaultUserGid="513"
>   defaultComputerGid="515"
>   skeletonDir="/etc/skel"
>   shadowAccount="1"
>   defaultMaxPasswordAge="45"
>   userSmbHome="\\PDC-SRV\%U"
>   userProfile="\\PDC-SRV\profiles\%U"
>   userHomeDrive="H:"
>   userScript="logon.bat"
>   mailDomain="example.com"
>   with_smbpasswd="0"
>   smbpasswd="/usr/bin/smbpasswd"
>   with_slappasswd="0"
>   slappasswd="/usr/sbin/slappasswd"

### /etc/smbldap-tools/smbldap_bind.conf

> slaveDN="cn=admin,dc=hybris95home,dc=local"
>   slavePw="HIDDEN"
>   masterDN="cn=admin,dc=hybris95home,dc=local"
>   masterPw="HIDDEN"

### samba.schema

samba.schema is correctly added, and recognized by phpLdapAdmin

## Detailed smbd interactive launch

> root@raspberrypi:/usr/sbin# ./smbd --interactive --debuglevel=3
>   Maximum core file size limits now 16777216(soft) -1(hard)
>   smbd version 4.2.10-Debian started.
>   Copyright Andrew Tridgell and the Samba Team 1992-2014
>   uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 egid=0
>   lp_load_ex: refreshing parameters
>   Initialising global parameters
>   Processing section "[global]"
>   Registered MSG_REQ_POOL_USAGE
>   Registered MSG_REQ_DMALLOC_MARK and LOG_CHANGED
>   lp_load_ex: refreshing parameters
>   Initialising global parameters
>   Processing section "[global]"
>   Processing section "[netlogon]"
>   Processing section "[homes]"
>   adding IPC service
>   added interface wlan0 ip=2a01:e34:ecf8:77e0:fa9e:f79f:4f7c:c821 bcast= netmask=ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff::
>   added interface wlan0 ip=192.168.1.38 bcast=192.168.1.255 netmask=255.255.255.0
>   loaded services
>   smbldap_search_domain_info: Searching for:[(&(objectClass=sambaDomain)(sambaDomainName=RASPBERRYPI))]
>   smbldap_open_connection: connection opened
>   ldap_connect_system: successful connection to the LDAP server
>   smbldap_search_domain_info: Got no domain info entries for domain
>   add_new_domain_info: Adding new domain
>   add_new_domain_info: failed to add domain dn= sambaDomainName=RASPBERRYPI,dc=hybris95home,dc=local with: Invalid DN syntax
>           invalid DN
>   smbldap_search_domain_info: Adding domain info for RASPBERRYPI failed with NT_STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL
>   pdb_init_ldapsam: WARNING: Could not get domain info, nor add one to the domain. We cannot work reliably without it.
>   pdb backend ldapsam:"ldap://raspberrypi.hybris95home.local/" did not correctly init (error was NT_STATUS_CANT_ACCESS_DOMAIN_INFO)

Comment: I tried removing the .local but it does not change anything

Comment: I also tried changing the sambaUnixIdPooldn value and it is not taken in count. Maybe smbldap.conf is incorrect ?

Answer (score 1):

I think this line

```
sambaUnixIdPooldn="sambaDomainName=${sambaDomain},${suffix}"
```

should be just

```
sambaUnixIdPooldn="${sambaDomain},${suffix}"
```

Comment: I have an issue with sambaUnixIdPooldn parameter. Weither I modify it or not, it is not taken in count. By the way, ${sambaDomain} takes hostname instead of sambaDomain parameter.